# Django 2.0.5 404 error-page not found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new in using Django and I am having some problems. When I run my server 'runserver' it shows 404 page not found. My project directory name is 'mysite' and my app name is 'webapp'. The problem I think is in 'urls' file. I have also put my app name in INSTALLED_APPS under the settings section.

This is the code in mysite/urls.py file:

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

 The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webapp', include("webapp.urls")),
]
```

And this is the code in webapp/urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = "index"),
]
```

I am using the latest Django version 2.0.5, I have tried to look up for this error but most of them seems to be of the older versions of Django.

I would appreciate any help, in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webapp/urls.py, you have to specify app name like
`app_name = "webapp"`

**mysite/urls**

```
urlpatterns = 
    [
        path('webapp/'), include() )
    ]
```

Note: parent urls must contain trailing slash.

Comment: @mahir, please add trailing in webapp/ in your root/urls

Comment: And now you can access server/webapp

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webapp/', include('webapp.urls')),
]
```

You forgot to add backslash after webapp in path "webapp/" which would help to redirect to further methods in views.

Answer (score 0):

As nothing has been defined for your root URL,it is thus empty and the 404 error occurs.To solve it,simply type the path to your view after the local server URL in your address bar.i.e **"127.0.0.1:8000/webapp"** or use **"localhost/name_of_url"**